# calculate throughput for 1G link

Tags: networking, performance-testing

I want to calculate the max network throughput on 1G Ethernet link. I understand how to estimate max rate in packets/sec units for 64-bytes frame:

```
IFG             12 bytes
MAC Preamble    8 bytes
MAC DA          6 bytes
MAC SA          6 bytes
MAC type        2 bytes
Payload         46 bytes
FCS             4 bytes
Total Frame size  -> 84 bytes
```

Now for 1G link we get:

```
1,000,000,000 bits/sec * 8 bits/byte => 1,488,096 fps
```

As I understand, this is a data link performance, correct?
But how to calculate throughput in megabits per second for different packets size, i.e. 64,128...1518? Also, how to calculate UDP/TCP throughput, since I have to consider headers overhead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max throughput over Ethernet = (Payload_size / (Payload_size + 38)) * Link bitrate

I.e. if you send 50 bytes of payload data, max throughput would be (50 / 88) * 1,000,000,000 for a 1G link, or about 568 Mbit/s. If you send 1000 bytes of payload, max throughput is (1000/1038) * 1,000,000,000 = 963 Mbit/s.

IP+UDP adds 28 bytes of headers, so if you're looking for data throughput over UDP, you should use this formula:

Max throughput over UDP = (Payload_size / (Payload_size + 66)) * Link bitrate

And IP+TCP adds 40 bytes of headers, so that would be:

Max throughput over TCP = (Payload_size / (Payload_size + 78)) * Link bitrate

Note that these are optimistic calculations. I.e. in reality, you might have extra options in the header data that increases the size of the headers, lowering payload throughput. You could also have packet loss that causes performance to drop.

Check out the Wikipedia article on the ethernet frame, and particularly the "Maximum throughput" section:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame